# How to set a table at the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I need my table to align at the bottom of my div, I've tried adding to the table's style the attributes : `position:absolute;bottom:0px` but it changed according to the page and not the div. I posted the full code (with img tag) cus i'm not sure about the influence of other tags.

//HTML

```
 <div>
            <img src="Img/flower" style="width: 960px; height: 474px; z-index: -1; position: absolute" />
            <table style="width:100%;height:120px;">
                  <tr>
            <td style="background-color:gray">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:green">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:yellow">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:red">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:lime">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:maroon">
            </td>
        </tr>
            </table></div>
```

Comment: Found the answer in my case the div and img must have the attribute position relative and the table will have position:absolue;bottom:0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your parent "div" and "img" should be declared as "position:relative" in this
>   case.
>   here is your solution:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
            <img src="Img/flower" style="width: 960px; height: 474px; z-index: -1; position: relative;">
            <table style="width: 100%; height: 120px;">
                  <tbody><tr>
            <td style="background-color:gray">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:green">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:yellow">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:red">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:lime">
            </td>
             <td style="background-color:maroon">
            </td>
        </tr>
            </tbody></table>


</div>
```

Comment: just adding it to the div ? without writing attributes in the table tag ? well its not working.. it's in the div's upper section...

Comment: yes because in your case you declare "img" element as "absolute", and for an absolute element to position there is requirement of any "relative element" as parent (here there is "div"). I have made your "img" as relative, your final working code is posted in my main thread

Comment: Yeah I just got it :) but will take your answer :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS Flexbox (check browser support) to vertical align:

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

```
<div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--bottom">…</div>
</div>
<style>    
.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.Aligner-item--bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
<style>
```

Comment: cant use JS only css

Comment: Sorry :) I dont know why I looked at it and thought about JS, cant use flex